# Convert UNIX Timestamp To Jalali Calendar

Tags: html, jquery

I want convert unix timestamp date to jalai calendar with jquery , i want set unix timestamp in attribute html tag and then show in tag

example:

1400/03/18 18:35:40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can easily use the following code :

##### Put the unix timestamp value in the attribute

```
<h1 unix_timestamp="1520482240"></h1>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $('[unix_timestamp]').each(function () {
            var unixtimestamp = $(this).attr("unix_timestamp");
            if (unixtimestamp != null) {
                let today = new Date(eval(unixtimestamp * 1000)).toLocaleDateString('fa-IR');
                var date = new Date(unixtimestamp * 1000);
                var hours = date.getHours();
                var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
                var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
                var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
                $(this).html(today + " " + formattedTime);
            }
        });
</script>
```

You can use it for any tag

Comment: The use of `eval()` isn't needed and should absolutely be removed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many js libraries to handle the task. The best approach is to use the built-in Intl library to format JS internal date to Jalaali calendar.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

The other way is to use of existing libraries, like this one
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jalaali-js

See the example below with both approaches implemented in code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get timestamp from html div tag
  const timestamp = $("#jalaali1").data("ts");
  // make js date instance from timestamp
  // js date uses millisecond hence multiplication by 1000
  const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

  // Format js date to jalaali using built-in Intl library
  const jalaaliDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US-u-ca-persian', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
    hour24: true
  }).format(date);

  // Set formatted date to div tag
  $("#jalaali1").html(jalaaliDate);

  // Format js date to jalaali using jalaali.js
  const jalaaliDate2 = jalaali.toJalaali(date);
  $("#jalaali2").html(jalaaliDate.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jalaali-js/dist/jalaali.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Using Intl (recommended)</strong>
<div id="jalaali1" data-ts="1654714722"></div>
<strong>Using jalaali.js</strong>
<div id="jalaali2" data-ts="1654714722"></div>
```